# SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE " ' .search_variable.' " doesn't work

Tags: php

Okay, so basically I'm trying to make a simple search system for some website products. My objective is to make it so that every time a user searches for something, he/she will only see the items that have titles that match the search term.

Here's my code product page code:

```
<form action="search.php" id="search_form" name="search_form" method="post">
<div class="form-field">
<label for="search-field">Search</label>
<input type="search" name="search_form" />
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
</form>
```

And here's my search.php code:

```
<?php
  include 'config.php';
  $x = $_POST['search_form'];
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM  WHERE product_name='".$x."'");
  $rowName = $row['name'];
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): 
?>
```

Comment: You're using `=`, not `LIKE`, and you're not using any wildcards. LIKE without wildcards will just do a case insensitive `equals` match.

Comment: There is no point in using `prepare()` if you are just going to concatenate the variable into your string anyways. Your code is still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using (mysql, postgres, sql server, oracle, something else)

Comment: The `name` attributes should be unique. You also don't define `$row` so `$rowName` will have no value and your usage of those two variables is unclear.

Comment: You are comparing the search entry with the product_price column in your query.

Comment: Woops! My bad...

Comment: Why is someone voting to close this question?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  WHERE product_name LIKE '%socks%'
```

This will match the following:

```
'socks for cats'
'green socks'
'knitted socks for giraffes'
```

Change PHP code to use `LIKE` to achieve the above.

Assuming you are using PDO:

```
include 'config.php';
$x = '%' . $_POST['search_form'] . '%';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM  WHERE product_name LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$x]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
   // do something with product data
}
```

mysqli

```
include 'config.php';
$x = '%' . $_POST['search_form'] . '%';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM  WHERE product_name LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $x);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
   // do something with product data
}
```

Comment: I am updating the answer.

Comment: Hello. First and foremost, thanks for your help! After adding the SQL and the mysqli code sections, I got this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping-cart\mypage.php on line 517

It could have to do with other parts of my code. Do you want me to send you anything else in case you can help?

Comment: @GreekPepsiman That is a syntax error, look at the PHP syntax before that line. It will tell you everything, hint `;` and `$stmt->bind_param("s", $x)`.